# amazon s3, upload file in folder in bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to a folder inside a s3 bucket.
I am doing the following in PHP:

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$bucket= $_POST['bucket'];

$actual_image_name = explode('.',$name)[0]."-".time().".".$ext;
$s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

The bucket name is a string sent to PHP and indicates a subfolder using a forward slash:

```
'<bucket name>/<subfolder>'
```

however, when I upload a new image to my bucket, it is uploaded to the bucket root.
How can I upload this file to the subfolder in my bucket?

Thx

Comment: If someone is using Laravel : `Storage::disk('s3')->put('created-directory-name/'.$fileName, $fileObject, 'public');`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The name of the sub folder should be added to the beginning of the filename and not to the end of the bucket name.

Comment: can you please give an example? something like `photos/bucket-732h44d2` if I want to use my `photos` folder?

Comment: for others, if your file name is ```test.png``` ,to insert into  ```(bucket1/folder1/)``` then try inserting into ```bucket1``` with the file name ```"folder1/test.png"  ( final path will be - bucket1/folder1/test.png)```